# How to test simple ruby method, with timing and config dependencies

Tags: ruby, testunit

I have this method:

```
def self.should_restart?
  if Konfig.get(:auto_restart_time).present?
    Time.now>=Time.parse(Konfig.get(:auto_restart_time)) && Utils.uptime_in_minutes>780
  end
end
```

In regular Ruby (not Rails) how would I go about testing this? I could monkeypatch Konfig and Utils to return what I want but that seems soooo ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use `timecop` as part of the solution (which also scores highly for me as "best-named gem, ever"). It is simple to use, and patches most sources of time data in sync, so that if for example your `Utils` module uses standard methods to assess time, it should have the same concept of "now" as `Time.now` shows.

Note this won't work if `Utils` is making a call to external API on another process, in which case you should stub it to return uptime values needed in your test assertions.

The following `rspec` snippet by way of example, and making some assumptions about what you have available (such as module under test being called `Server`)

```
describe "#should_restart?"
  before :each do
    Timecop.travel( Time.parse("2013-08-01T12:00:00") )
    Server.start # Just a guess
    # Using `mocha` gem here
    Konfig.expect(:get).with(:auto_restart_time).returns( "18:00:00" )
  end

  after :each do
    Timecop.return
  end

  it "should be false if the server has just been started" do
    Server.should_restart?.should be_false
  end

  it "should be false before cutoff time" do
    Timecop.travel( Time.parse("2013-08-02T16:00:00") )
    Server.should_restart?.should be_false
  end

  it "should be true when the server has been up for a while, after cutoff time" do
    Timecop.travel( Time.parse("2013-08-02T18:05:00") )
    Server.should_restart?.should be_true
  end
end
```

Comment: And how about the Konfig class? What would you do there?

Comment: I have suggested in my snippet to use `mocha` to stub it with a value for the test. The syntax for it is from memory, mind, it may need tweaking. Try and avoid asserting exactly how many times it is called - it is enough to just know that the config value is used to control the behaviour of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Use mock framework
like rspec-mock, rr mock